# Listening for headset button input not working

Tags: android, android-studio, headset

From what I have read from multiple other questions online, when listening for a headphone button input you're supposed to have a receiver for the MEDIA_BUTTON action, and register that receiver in your manifest.
My code is as below:
(Manifest)

```
...
    <receiver android:name="listeners.HeadphoneButtonBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
...
```

(Receiver)

```
public class HeadphoneButtonBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static short clickAmount = 0;

    public HeadphoneButtonBroadcastReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("@@DEBUG", "HeadphoneButtonBroadcastReceiver::onReceive");
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) return;

        KeyEvent keyEvent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (keyEvent == null) return;

        if (keyEvent.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return;

        // Doing things here
    }
}
```

where the receiver is in a package called `listeners`.

However, I can't get the log to work either by doing this or doing some fixes I've found online (set the priority of the filter really high, try setting the receiver dependency in code instead of in the manifest).

I know the button input itself works, because I tried overwriting the `onKeyDown` function in my Activity, and it did go through there. However, I want to be able to listen to the click even when the Activity isn't the current window.
My target SDK version is API 25 (7.1.1) if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own broadcast receiver, you can try broadcast receiver provided by support library.

```
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Like the documentation says, `MediaButtonReceiver` will look a `Service` which has `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` intent filter, and handle the key event in a service

```
<service android:name=".MediaPlaybackService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The implementation of the service

```
public class MediaPlaybackService extends Service {

    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat;
    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlaybackService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "myMediaSession");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: media button intent");
        MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSessionCompat, intent);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```